A fantasy book about boy who was raised by bears

Gods/elementals first attempt at a human goes rogue and is trapped beneath the earth (the bad guy uses lightning as his element and is the only one who can)
There is a kid who was raised by bears and can speak their language. The kid travels to learn to use all elements to defeat bad guy (and uses a bear claw type weapon)
There is a scene where the kid plays a sports game with the bear cubs and the adoptive bear parents watch?
The water elemental is the love interest? maybe she dies?
It is a series


I assume the "bad guy" is that "first human" that they trapped beneath the Earth based on your phrasing?
